# Program always predicts only 1 class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I was working on leaf disease detection and tried to implement CNN on [SpMohanty's PlantVillage-dataset](https://github.com/spMohanty/PlantVillage-Dataset/tree/master/raw/color). 
It has `38 classes` with variable images in each class ranging from 1500 to 3000 images/class. `Total images = 54303`

Here's my [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12XKeIDJWImHbVXaXnXiSsZFBi63OuK3u?usp=sharing). The issue is when predicting an image it always throws the 1st class the model trains upon. I don't understand why.
Here's the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 64, 64, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 21, 21, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 21, 21, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 21, 21, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 21, 21, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 21, 21, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 21, 21, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 21, 21, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 21, 21, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 10, 10, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 10, 10, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 10, 10, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 10, 10, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 10, 10, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 10, 10, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 5, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 3200)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              3277824   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 1024)              4096      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 38)                38950     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 38)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 3,600,294
Trainable params: 3,597,414
Non-trainable params: 2,880
_________________________________________________________________
```

Although the model achieved 98.94% validation accuracy and 99.7% train accuracy.
The model history is as below:

```
Epoch 1/10
678/678 [==============================] - 691s 1s/step - loss: 0.0527 - accuracy: 0.9836 - val_loss: 0.0521 - val_accuracy: 0.9840
Epoch 2/10
678/678 [==============================] - 705s 1s/step - loss: 0.0283 - accuracy: 0.9900 - val_loss: 0.0926 - val_accuracy: 0.9787
Epoch 3/10
678/678 [==============================] - 680s 1s/step - loss: 0.0205 - accuracy: 0.9925 - val_loss: 0.0228 - val_accuracy: 0.9924
Epoch 4/10
678/678 [==============================] - 692s 1s/step - loss: 0.0170 - accuracy: 0.9938 - val_loss: 0.0741 - val_accuracy: 0.9828
Epoch 5/10
678/678 [==============================] - 679s 1s/step - loss: 0.0148 - accuracy: 0.9946 - val_loss: 0.0503 - val_accuracy: 0.9860
Epoch 6/10
678/678 [==============================] - 682s 1s/step - loss: 0.0129 - accuracy: 0.9953 - val_loss: 0.0323 - val_accuracy: 0.9918
Epoch 7/10
678/678 [==============================] - 691s 1s/step - loss: 0.0110 - accuracy: 0.9960 - val_loss: 0.0393 - val_accuracy: 0.9890
Epoch 8/10
678/678 [==============================] - 701s 1s/step - loss: 0.0098 - accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0420 - val_accuracy: 0.9875
Epoch 9/10
678/678 [==============================] - 692s 1s/step - loss: 0.0090 - accuracy: 0.9967 - val_loss: 0.0687 - val_accuracy: 0.9855
Epoch 10/10
678/678 [==============================] - 690s 1s/step - loss: 0.0082 - accuracy: 0.9971 - val_loss: 0.0414 - val_accuracy: 0.9894
```

This looks like a case of model overfitting but I did a confusion matrix for various train_test_splits and I found 80% train was best in that. So I don't think the model is overfitting. Also it always predict the first class, I tried changing the name of the class [eg: Apple_scab to Z_Apple_Scab], it then started printing the output as: Apple_Blackrot (next label alphabetically after Apple_scab, which now became 1st label during training.)

T.I.A.

**[Update]:**
Here is the predict function that I use to predict new images...

```
imAr  =  cvtim(impath)
savedclfmodel  =  pickle.load(open(model_file,'rb'))
pred  =  savedclfmodel.predict(imAr)
lb  =  pickle.load(open(lb_file,'rb'))
ret_data  =  lb.inverse_transform(pred)[0]
print("Predicted: ",ret_data)
```

where cvtim(image_path) converts the image to array using `keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array`
and `savedclfmodel` opens the previously saved model-weight file using `pickle.load()` and stored in `lb`, which is then used to find inverse_transform to get the predicted label

Answer (score 0):

Your training data looks good with high training and validation accuracy. I see no sign of over fitting. It is normal for the validation loss to oscillated to a small degree around a lowest point. You do not show enough code to figure out what is going wrong. I assume you are using model.predict on your test set. Something like

```
predictions=model.predict(data,batch_size=batch_size, steps=steps, verbose=0 )
# data is your test data provided as an array or from a generator
# then use the code below to find the predicted class
for i in range (0,len(predictions):
        predicted_class_number=predictions[i].argmax()
        # this will be an integer denoting the class
```

Comment: I used inverse_transform on predictions. Even if I print predictions (which returns a list of 1's and 0's based on label-size), I tend to get [0,1,0...0] everytime. Based on this output I exclaimed that the program outputs only the first label (index_position=1)

Comment: It seems all my probabilities are either 0 or 1. I've updated the question as well! My output if I print the predictions is: `[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]`

Comment: not sure what is wrong. Why not use model.save to save the model and model.load to load the model and avoid all the pickle stuff. Make sure that if you did any processing on the validation data you do the SAME  processing on the input data like resizing it or scaling it..